# Adding Primary keys and a Relationship to tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have compiled the following as an example of what i have done so far and would like to know how i should continue:

```
CREATE TABLE tblMembers
(
Member_ID int,
Name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE tblHorses
(
Horse_ID int,
Name varchar(255),
Age int(10),
Member_ID int(10)
);
```

So i would like to specify both Member_ID and Horse_ID as the PK and create the relationship between tblMembers and tblHorses using Member_ID

I would also like to make the ID columns auto incremental

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you ware asking?

```
CREATE TABLE tblMembers (
    Member_ID int identity(1, 1) not null primary key
    Name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE tblHorses (
    Horse_ID int identity(1, 1) not nullprimary key
    Name varchar(255),
    Age int,
    Member_ID int references tblMembers(member_id)
);
```

Storing something like "age" in a column is a really bad idea.  After all, age continually changes.  You should be storing something like the date of birth.

Answer (score 1):

Use this. **[Fiddler Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c56d1)**

Refer this for creating [Primary Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189039.aspx),[Foreign Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189049.aspx), [Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) .

```
CREATE TABLE tblMembers
(
    Member_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key,
    Name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE tblHorses
(
    Horse_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key,
    Name varchar(255),
    Age int,
    Member_ID int Foreign key (Member_ID) REFERENCES tblMembers(Member_ID)
);
```

**Note:** `MS SQL doesn't support length in Integer Type.`

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE tblMembers
(
Member_ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name varchar(255)
PRIMARY KEY (MEMBER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE tblHorses
(
Horse_ID int,
Name varchar(255),
Age int(10),
FOREIGN KEY (MEMBER_ID) REFERENCES tblMembers(MEMBER_ID)
PRIMARY KEY (HORSE_ID)
);
```

Following W3Schools' examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
CREATE TABLE tblMembers (
Member_ID int identity(1, 1) not null 
Name varchar(255)
PRIMARY KEY (Member_ID )
);

CREATE TABLE tblHorses (
Horse_ID int identity(1, 1) not null 
Name varchar(255),
Age int,
PRIMARY KEY (Horse_ID) 
Member_ID int references tblMembers(member_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblMembers](
    [Member_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblMembers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Member_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblHorses](
    [Horse_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Age] [int] NULL,
    [Member_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblHorses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Horse_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblHorses]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblHorses_tblMembers] FOREIGN KEY([Member_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblMembers] ([Member_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblHorses] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblHorses_tblMembers]
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

For Auto Incremental, you have to set PK column as `identity(seed, value)`

```
CREATE TABLE tblMembers (
    Member_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    Name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE tblHorses (
    Horse_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    Name VARCHAR(255),
    Age INT,
    Member_ID int REFERENCES tblMembers(Member_id)
);
```